# What is an effective means to make divisibility tests a mathematical 'habit', particularly for algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, education

[Divisibility tests](http://www.mathsisfun.com/divisibility-rules.html) are a useful problem-solving technique for particularly dealing with larger numbers (thousands etc) and algebraic problems. However, I have always found that many students will just reach for the calculator, many not even realising the simpler tests, such as anything divisible by 2, 5 or 10.

What is an effective means to help 'train' these skills in students as a problem solving and 'thinking' skill?

Comment: Do not allow calculators.

Comment: You could cut off their hands, but that has unfortunate side effects. Seriously, I don’t that there are any. You can teach the divisibility tests, and you can drill students until they can use them very successfully on demand, but I know of no way to internalize the demand.

Comment: @GitGud: That’s not really a solution, because there are things for which calculators are the right tool. What we really want is for students to learn to choose an appropriate tool.

Comment: To me, the utility of divisibility tests is to give a glimpse of the beauty of "pattern" or "order". The fact that such rules exist at all is the interesting part. Applying them is rather mundane and better accomplished with a calculator, even if it does take a second or two longer to type a long number.

Comment: Now seriously, authoritatively infuse them with the idea that calculators are for lesser people or something.

Comment: The practical utility of "casting out nines" has nearly vanished.

Comment: Sigh, even in otherwise justified usage of calculators, I've seen them students laboriously type steps like "$\times 1$" or "$-0$", so I'm afraid all hope is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The students are the smart ones. If the calculator is giving the easiest way to get the answer of course the best is to use the calculator.

But what would happen if the problem is so designed that a calculator would be of little or no help.

Calculators don\t help much to show that $n(n+1)$ is even. That $a+10b+100c+1000d$ is divisible by $9$ if and only if $a+b+c+d$ is divisible by $9$. That $3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3}}}}}-1$ is even.

... and these are still not clever exercises.

**Addendum:**
Because it is relevant, I would like to advocate against training students to mindlessly using some tricks, techniques, procedures. Students in their brute state are critical enough by nature. Pushing them to do some task for which there is not a clear purpose is what turns them into bad students. In mathematics we often focus too much in teaching the techniques, but what is more important is the purpose for those techniques. That is why you often see students that compulsively 'simplify' solutions, even partial solutions, or expand brackets for no reason.

This applies to any technique. Give them exercises in which it is clear the purpose of a technique. Being able to identify a purpose, not knowing lots of procedures, is what makes them able to solve new problems. Procedures and techniques can be googled most of the time.

Comment: Exactly, Franklin, that is part of where I am getting at with my question.

Comment: @Damien Your question seems to be asking for a way to encourage students to use divisibility tests even when a calculator will suffice. If you are wanting exercises in which a calculator is of little or no help, you may want to revise your question.

Comment: @AustinMohr We shouldn't teach students to be stupid. If a calculator is the best answer, pushing to use other methods will make no sense in their heads. The key idea is that if a technique is still relevant regardless of technology, there will be situations that will show it. The professor is the one that should be smart and dedicated enough to find those.

Comment: @AustinMohr clarified to specify algebraic divisibility tests as well.

Comment: @Franklin.vp I agree on all counts. My comment was merely that Damien's original question seemed to be asking for a way to convince students to *always* use divisibility tests even when they aren't appropriate.

Comment: My calculator says that $3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3}}}}}-1$ is divisible by $2$. The result is $\mathtt{Inf}$.

Comment: **Divisible**: $a$ is divisible by $b$ if $a=bc$ with $c$ integer. Divisible is a mathematical concept with a specific meaning that is not the _common language_ term that could mean 'being able to divide in some way'. Can you write Inf as $2$ times and integer?

Comment: @Franklin.vp I was joking.

Answer (score 4):

You could race them; if you can always beat them in your head when they use a calculator, that would convince them. Then have them race each other, one with a calculator, one without, then switch until they get good at it.

Comment: True, and most of the time, I do beat them to the answer.